# Find outlier records considering in dataframe

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, data-cleaning, outliers

I am building a body measurement prediction machine learning model.

I want to drop records with anomalous set of %Fat, Neck, Chest, Abdom, Hip, Thigh, Knee, Ankle, Biceps, F-arm and Wrist with respect to Age, Weight and Height collectively.

I mean if a record with 25 age, 190 Weight and 75 Height has has a certain inter quartile range for %Fat or Neck or Chest, all the values of these columns should lie within interquartile range and any outlier may be replaced with mean value. [this is what my dataset looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie6aO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure, if I get how exactly you want to clean outliers. I wrote a small formula for a project to clean the dataset based on a given quantile. What is special about this formula is, that it works in two stages. First, it gets the quantiles for each column to clean based on the given percentage level and second, it deletes all rows with values above the given threshhold. The two step process allows to delete less values, in contrast to iterating over each column. The code looks as follows:

```
def clean_quantiles(dataset, variables=[], frame=[0.025, 0.975]):
    df = dataset.copy()
    quantiles = []
    
    for name in variables:
        quantiles.append([df[name].quantile(frame[0]), df[name].quantile(frame[1])])
    
    for i in range(0, len(variables)):
        df = df[df[variables[i]].between(quantiles[i][0], quantiles[i][1])]
    
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    return df
```

- "dataset" is where you put your pandas data frame
- "variables" should be a list of columns to check
- "frame" contains the percentage outlier you want to exclude